# Skulpt example not work in Plunker

Tags: javascript, plunker, skulpt

I'm new to Plunker so this may be a noob question...But I really struggled a long time and haven't figured it out yet.

I tried to test the example code published on Skulpt's main site in Plunker but it just didn't work. But it did work in local server.
[Here's my plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/MaqDuUEbHUuy4lvUA6Bw?p=preview)

Here's the code:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt-stdlib.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

</head> 

<body> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
// output functions are configurable.  This one just appends some text
// to a pre element.
function outf(text) { 
    var mypre = document.getElementById("output"); 
    mypre.innerHTML = mypre.innerHTML + text; 
} 
function builtinRead(x) {
    if (Sk.builtinFiles === undefined || Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x] === undefined)
            throw "File not found: '" + x + "'";
    return Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x];
}
// Here's everything you need to run a python program in skulpt
// grab the code from your textarea
// get a reference to your pre element for output
// configure the output function
// call Sk.importMainWithBody()
function runit() { 
   var prog = document.getElementById("yourcode").value; 
   var mypre = document.getElementById("output"); 
   mypre.innerHTML = ''; 
   Sk.pre = "output";
   Sk.configure({output:outf, read:builtinRead}); 
   (Sk.TurtleGraphics || (Sk.TurtleGraphics = {})).target = 'mycanvas';
   var myPromise = Sk.misceval.asyncToPromise(function() {
       return Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, prog, true);
   });
   myPromise.then(function(mod) {
       console.log('success');
   },
       function(err) {
       console.log(err.toString());
   });
} 
</script> 

<h3>Try This</h3> 
<form> 
<textarea id="yourcode" cols="40" rows="10">import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.forward(100)

print "Hello World" 
</textarea><br /> 
<button type="button" onclick="runit()">Run</button> 
</form> 
<pre id="output" ></pre> 
<!-- If you want turtle graphics include a canvas -->
<div id="mycanvas"></div> 

</body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code requests `http` resources and is being run from the `https` version of Plunker. Plunker's editor can be opened either in `https` or in `http` though I encourage the former.

Modern browsers will now block the loading of `http` resources from an `https` website (such as the preview of your Plunk). You can observe this by opening the developer console where you will see messages about blocked requests.

You have two options:

1. Open your saved Plunk via `http` ([your plunk over http](http://plnkr.co/edit/MaqDuUEbHUuy4lvUA6Bw?p=preview))
2. Adjust the resources that your plunk requests to come from an `https://` scheme:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="https://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="https://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt-stdlib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please consider accepting the answer if that is the case Liang Yi.